# How to show users list in content (view) or vice versa?

Tags: 7, search, ajax

I want to show content as well as users in one view. I tried it by using entity reference and attaching 2 displays within a view, but no success. May be I am doing it wrong or it is not possible. I dont know. Is it possible anyway?

What I am trying to do?

I am creating an autocomplete view to use in search box.

Comment: What is the commonality that you are showing?  Views needs a base.  Are you trying to show Flags, the users who have made them and the nodes they are on?  Then the commonality is the flag and you should start the view there.

Comment: I guess I did not get you. You mean users who have flagged a content or authored it? No. Base? Not sure what it means, but flags are usually used in relationships section in the views. Well, if this is what it means, why cant we use entity reference? Currently, we have users autocomplete and nodes autocomplete separately. You can use one at a time in your search box. I want to combine both so that a user can search for both users and content with autocomplete suggestions. An autocomplete solution with both users and content at the same time.

Comment: There got to be a solution out there. Anything? Just need a solution for this problem. May be a drop down with the search bar which 1. when a user selects an entity, only that entity is searched 2. Also, it provides suggestions based on the option selected from the dropdown. Custom search module satisfies the first part only. May be a php script would be handy at this point which loads the autocomplete view for the selected option from the dropdown. Dont know how to do that. Just a thought

Comment: Are you familiar with the "dataTables" module? And the "search box" that you get from that module? That facility allows to type (eg) "Umair abc", which will dynamically (in the browser) limit the views results to only those rows that contain in ANY field the strings "Umair" AND "abc". Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? If so I'd be happy to convert this comment to a more detailed (real) answer.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Not familiar with this module. I am looking to achieve an autocomplete solution which shows users and content (e.g article etc), relevant to keywords in the search box. When click on the user, it should take to the profile page and when click on content, it should take to the content or node page

Comment: @Umair Well, if you're not familiar with this module, I recommend you add it to your list of modules to review/study (I love it ...). If you want, have a look at [this](http://drupal.placeto.be/answers) Views example, which uses dataTables module. for anonymous users, the column with "Answered by" only shows user names, while for authenticated users they are shown as links to the user profile. In the search box (upper right of the views display), type something like "Pierre vbo" (or any other combination you want), and see what happens. Not using "autocomplete", but maybe a good compromise?